# What is eval doing in this code?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

```
buildenv=`make -C $SRCROOT buildenvvars`
eval $buildenv make -C $SRCROOT/sys/boot clean
```

what is "eval $buildenv" for?
can expand to 
`make -C $SRCROOT buildenvvars` make -C $SRCROOT/sys/boot clean ??

Comment: Run `make -C $SRCROOT buildenvvars` and see what output you get.  I am guessing it returns a string with a series of `var=value` pairs.  `eval` sets the environment variables for the second `make` command with the help of string (key value pairs) returned by the first `make`.  Doesn't seem like a nice way of doing things.

Comment: If it was just var=value, `env` would suffice ... or even just putting it *after* `make`

Comment: Note that in the `buildenv=` line, the `make` command is in backquotes not normal single-quotes. This means it'll be executed and its output saved in the variable `buildenv`. Thus the correct command is `eval [output from make -C $SRCROOT buildenvvars] make -C $SRCROOT/sys/boot clean`. As @codeforester said, that output is probably a bunch of var=value pairs, and I'd also agree that this is a fragile way of doing it.

Comment: how could I make  codeforester's comment as answer?